# Passing a databound int in a gridview to a function via an on click event in the grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Basically I'm trying to pass this int to a function from a link button in a grid view

here is what I'm doing atm but I am receiving an error.. I've been stuck on this all morning..

Thanks for any help.

Here is the code.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkAttachment" 
   ToolTip="<%$ Resources:DocumentsContent, Viewdocument%>" 
   Visible='<%# (int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DOCUMENT_ID") > 0 %>' 
   OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank'; setDownloadDoc();" 
   OnClick='lnkAttachment_Click(<%#(int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DOCUMENT_ID")%>)'>

  <asp:Image ID="imgSelect0" runat="server"  src="../Images/IconEdit.gif" border="0" alt="<%$ Resources:DocumentsContent, Select%>" />

</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: try to give specification of what you want to do.

Comment: You're receiving an error? What error?
What's being rendered to the page, and what do you want to be rendered to the page? People want to help, but you've got to help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a asp control inside a GridView you need to set a `Command` to the LinkButton. You can not use the `OnClick` property.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnkAttachment" 
   ToolTip="<%$ Resources:DocumentsContent, Viewdocument%>" 
   Visible='<%# (int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DOCUMENT_ID") > 0 %>' 
   OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank'; setDownloadDoc();" 
   CommandName="lnkAttachmentClick"
   CommandValue='<%#(int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DOCUMENT_ID")%>'>
  <asp:Image ID="imgSelect0" runat="server"  src="../Images/IconEdit.gif" border="0" alt="<%$ Resources:DocumentsContent, Select%>" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

The code behind would be like:

```
private void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName) {
        case "lnkAttachmentClick":
            int document_id = (int)e.CommandArgument;
            // Write your code here
            break;
}
```

Finally, you need to add the `onrowcommand` property in your GridView with the name of the function.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
</asp:GridView>
```

You can view [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/564619/Example-of-gridview-rowcommand-on-Button-Click) a simple tutorial no how to use the `RowCommand` event in a `GridView`.

Answer (score 0):

if you developing for web you can use query string or session as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Gawd webforms sucks.

Try using the CommandArgument attribute of the LinkButton. Look up how to use it.

You're not meant to actually call a method in the OnClick attribute, i.e. lnkAttachment_Click(stuff). You're meant to specify the name of the event handler and that's all, so lnkAttachment_Click.

Actually, screw it. Just use a normal <a> link and set all your own attributes. Use a data-something html5 attribute to store your integer and have the postback called from a client click handler. Avoid WebForms controls wherever you can, because it just makes good, modern web development so much harder.

Answer (score 0):

Like David said, try adding commandArgument to your Link:

```
 CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
```

Then in your code behind, get the value like this maybe?

```
string Value = GridView2.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument.ToString())].Cells[0].Text;
```

I then used ResponseRedirects & Query strings. to pass the value around.

Hope this can help.